# Excel VBA - Search for certain criteria in a column and copy that row to new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA so I'm not sure what is wrong with my code or if this is the best way to do what I want. I have a gigantic raw data sheet titled "Data" that has lots of columns, one of them being the date. First I want the macro to create four new worksheets titled spring, summer, fall and winter and place them at the end of the sheet count. Then I want to search through the date column in "Data" for a month, and copy that corresponding row into the season worksheet that corresponds to that month. This is what I have so far- I am getting an error with my if then statements. I defined the date column as an array but I am not sure if I even need to define it at all. However when this macro will be used the number of rows in "data" will not be constant. Thanks.

```
Sub Copy_Sorted_Data()

    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Spring"
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Summer"
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Fall"
    Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Winter"

    Dim Data As Worksheet
    Dim Spring As Worksheet
    Dim Summer As Worksheet
    Dim Fall As Worksheet
    Dim Winter As Worksheet
    Dim Entered() As Date
    Dim size As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Data").Columns(1))
    ReDim numbers(size)

    For i = 1 To size
        numbers(i) = Cells(i, 9).Value
    Next i

    If Entered = March Or April Or May Then ActiveSheet.Row.Value.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Spring")
    If Entered = June Or July Or August Then ActiveSheet.Row.Value.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summer")
    If Entered = September Or October Or November Then ActiveSheet.Row.Value.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Fall")
    If Entered = December Or January Or February Then ActiveSheet.Row.Value.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Winter")

    End If
    End If
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you set a command after `then` of you `if` statements they don't need `End If`, so I think you should edit your code.

Comment: Okay I will change that. However I am getting a type mismatch error so I think it might have something to do with my "entered" variable being defined as a date.

Comment: How do you read `entered` from `Data` sheet? You just read `numbers`

Comment: Okay.. So I changed my if statement to read "if numbers = " and I am still getting the type mismatch error.

Comment: Check my answer for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st. Remove these codes:

```
If Entered = March Or April Or May Then ActiveSheet.Row.Value.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Spring")
If Entered = June Or July Or August Then ActiveSheet.Row.Value.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Summer")
If Entered = September Or October Or November Then ActiveSheet.Row.Value.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Fall")
If Entered = December Or January Or February Then ActiveSheet.Row.Value.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Winter")
End If
End If
End If
End If
```

2nd. When you want to read data from column 9 then find `size` from that column:

```
size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Data").Columns(9))
```

3rd. When you want to Find your result:

```
Dim SpringRows as long
Dim Summer as long
Dim Fall as Long
Dim WinterRows as Long

For i = 1 To size
    numbers(i) = Cells(i, 9).Value
    'working with month numbers is better
    If (Month(numbers(i)) = 3) OR (Month(numbers(i)) = 4) OR (Month(numbers(i)) = 5) then 
        SpringRows = SpringRows + 1
        Worksheets("Spring").Cells(SpringRows, 1).Value = numbers(i)
    End If
    ' ... and so on, for others
Next i
```

Comment: I still received the same error with this code and I ended up doing something else completely different that works fine now. Thank you for your help though.